# Now i want Page D pop to Page B How to do it

Tags: flutter

My business scenario is that within a page, I need to go to the multi-level page in succession, and select the last level page, then return the parameters to the previous page. What should I do?

- Page A Navigator
- push to Page B
- Page B Navigator
- push to Page C
- Page C Navigator
- push to Page D

Now i want Page D pop to Page B

How to do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [popUntil](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popUntil.html). Replace your Page B with '/login' example.

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/login'));

//a.dart
onTap: () {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    new MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => BPage(),
      settings: RouteSettings( // set route settings
        name: "bpage" // you will use this string in popUntil
      )
    ),
  );
},


//d.dart
child: GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('bpage')); // here
  },
  child: Text('return A'),
),
```

Comment: Yes, I used this method, but there was another mistake.This mistakes{Failed assertion : line 1995 pos 12:'!_debugLocked': is not true.}

Comment: I pasted the code below. Please check it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Coding24h I updated my answer. Please edit your code in `a.dart` and `d.dart`

Comment: @Coding24h and you can use this `RouteSettings` in different pages if my example doesn't match yours.